# For WPF, Is it overkill to use a setter to set the itemtemplate property?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate, setter

When I searched the internet to find out how to set the itemtemplate for a listbox, I found an example where they used a Style Setter in the window.resources to do this. So, I have a couple of options, I can either create a datatemplate in my window.resources, or, create a Style Setter. Would it be overkill to set the style instead of the datatemplate? Which method should I use?

Thank You.

Comment: sometimes those setter based examples are to get around some wierd case where they couldn't do it the simple way.  I'd just use a datatemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't say one or the other is better, it depends. Implicit DataTemplates are a nice way to globally (even if just for part of the visual tree) how a Type should look. While using ItemTemplate allows you to indicate how it should look in a given ItemsControl (i.e. ListBox, ComboBox, etc.).

You can even use a combination of both of them, which allows you have a "default" look, but customize it per control or control type.

Even with ItemTemplate, you can set it globally for say all ListBoxes, or for just one ListBox instance. So again, sometimes one method is better, sometimes not. It depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Styles in general are used to apply the same values to different instances of the same type. If this is not the case there is no need to create a style at all.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to make a `<DataTemplate>` for the type of item and then let WPF figure it out.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Task}">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TaskName}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Priority}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<List ItemSource="{Binding MyListOfTaskItems"/>
```